# How to show key content of WiFi profile starts with hash # using cmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am running the following code,

```
netsh wlan show profile name="#Philip" key=clear
```

This will show saved WiFi key content in clear text.
Problem is when i run this code am getting following error,

```
Profile "" is not found on the system.
```

My other saved WiFi passwords are showing without any issues. Then only i realize this wifi network ssid starts with hash `#`. So, now my need and question is,

**How to show key content of the WiFi SSID that starts with # ? or any other similar solutions for my need ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this method to display the profile of a WIFI properties

```
netsh wlan show profiles
```

You'll get a list of all the networks you've used in the past.

```
netsh wlan show profile name=profilename key=clear
```

For example:

```
netsh wlan show profile name=test key=clear
```

Since you can not use # in the name, you can try this method :

```
netsh wlan show profile name=*#test key=clear
```

output :

```
Connectivity settings
---------------------
    Number of SSIDs        : 1
    SSID name              : "#test"
    Network type           : Infrastructure
    Radio type             : [ Any Radio Type ]
    Vendor extension          : Not present
```

Comment: Thaks a lot. That * is what am looking for. It works now.. `*#test`